# more elegant way to convert Nodejs Buffer of utf8 to json?

Tags: json, node.js, utf-8, buffer

Is there a more elegant way to convert a Buffer, in nodejs to json than this?

```
JSON.parse(payload.OriginalEvent.Metadata.toString('utf8'))
```

If I do

```
payload.OriginalEvent.Metadata.toJSON()
```

I get a utf8 encoded string.

I feel as though I may be doing extra work that is already wrapped up in some buffer method.

---EDIT
awesome, I fixed an (unrelated) bug while trying to get this data for you.

```
console.log(payload.OriginalEvent.Metadata);
console.log(payload.OriginalEvent.Metadata.toJSON());
console.log(payload.OriginalEvent.Metadata.toString('utf8'));


<Buffer 7b 22 65 76 65 6e 74 54 79 70 65 4e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 74 65 73 74 69 6e 67 45 76 65 6e 74 22 7d>

{ type: 'Buffer',
  data: [ 123, 34, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 78, 97, 109, 101, 34, 58,34, 116, 101,115, 116,105, 110, 103, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 34,125 ] }

{"eventTypeName":"testingEvent"}
```

however, for the last example, it's now a string so I must json.parse it in order to access the property

I hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. In your first example you are converting *from* JSON and in the second you are just calling a method to presumable get an object. Can you clarify with more examples if expected input and output?

Comment: There really isn't a better way that I've found. If you find yourself using this pattern more than a couple time, I suggest writing a module that will safely convert and parse a buffer to a JSON object.

Comment: @Freyday that's what I suspected. I was just hoping there would be something built in that would work. not really sure what toJSON is for since a buffer is by default encoded with utf8 you'll all ways have to decode.